# SAX Parser not accepting the returned XML data

Tags: java, android, .net, xml

I am trying to use [SAX XML Parse](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)) in one of my Android application to read the returned XML from a `.Net` based web API.
Like this:

```
URL finalUri = new URL("...");
...
bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
   stringBuffer.append(line + newLine);
bufferReader.close();

serverResponse = stringBuffer.toString();
XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
xmhandler xmgp = new xmhandler();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(xmgp);

xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(finalUri.openStream()));
```

From API I tried returning result in two formats as a `string`  which returns XML as a string:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"...
```

And as a `XDocument` which returns result in following format:

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8"},
```

But in both case the SAX XML Parser throws a `SAXException e`

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Can anyone please help me to send the XML in the right format acceptable to SAX Parser from my API? The documentation of the SAX parser says that it requires a `(a character stream, a byte stream, or a URI).` How can i return any of these from my API?

The API function is like this:

```
    private string GetResponseString(string baseGooglePlaceApiUrl)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseGooglePlaceApiUrl);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Accept = "application/xml";

        string responseStream;
        var responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseObj.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseStream;

        //return new string[] { responseStream };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string as a stream like

```
InputStream stringStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseStream.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
saxParser.parse(stringStream, handler);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through `XML Reader` rather `SAX Parser` object? with your answer i am getting alto of problems like need to raise the API level for `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and other related issues.

Comment: You can ignore that `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` argument. It'll still work. And of course you can read that xml via XML read. Again using string as well like `XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(stringStream);`

Comment: Ok passed that. But Still getting error `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 17: not well-formed (invalid token)` the returned string is `"<?xml version=\"1.0\"` column 17 is actually character `\\` .. Is this because of characters?

Comment: Can you post that xml? Or you can copy the string and check for validation here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp